# Firebase Ondisconnect

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase backend. I want to implement firebase onDisconnect functionality on backend. I have 100 or so authorised firebase users and each one will have a unique id generated by firebase. How can I know which user is not connected right now. I have seen examples and everyone is telling this code;

```
admin.database().ref().child(".info/connected").on("value", function (snap) {
  connected = snap.val() === true;
  if (connected) {

  } else {

  }
});
```

How can I get that unique firebase id associated with each user using above code or how i can know which is disconnected?

Comment: You'll want to use `.info/connected` and [`onDisconnect`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works) for this use-case. There's a great sample [presence app in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample), which uses a push ID to identify a connection, and the user's UID to identify each user. Instead of repeating it here, I recommend you check it out there and post back if you have problems implementing it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all while user open application at that time set one entry with their current state like

```
users :
{
  "784823468sugfsdjf":"online",
  "3223232fdfdfdffdf":"online",
  "y32y32y32y32y3y23":"online",
  "3b2jg434jg343g4h3":"offline"
}
```

Now update all user's status using

```
admin.database().ref().child(".info/connected").on("value", function (snap) {
  connected = snap.val() === true;
  if (connected) {
      updated(uid,"Online");
  } else {
      updated(uid,"offline");
  }
});
```

By this way you will get all user's current state.